# Google Drive API multiple individual get requests to retrieve all parents is slow, is there a better way?

Tags: java, performance, google-drive-api

I am using Google Drive API v3 - I need to retrieve all the folders in my Google Drive and then get all of the parents of each retrieved folder in a list of strings.

As far as I can work out the way to do this is to retrieve the list of folders, then iterate through and individually request the parent of each folder, then if a parent of that folder exists retrieve the parent of that folder - and so on, constructing a list of strings that way. However, this requires a huge number of requests for large folder structures, and as such runs slowly - is there a better way?

My code for reference (sorry it is a bit messy, I'm trying to learn to use this API):

```
public static List<File> retrieveAllFolders(Drive service) throws IOException
{
    //List of folders
    List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
    //Construct request to get the folders
    Drive.Files.List request = service.files().list().setQ("mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'");
    //Loop through as long as there is more 'pages' to iterate through
    do
    {
        try
        {
            //Execute the request
            FileList files = request.execute();
            //Add all the retrieved files into the result
            result.addAll(files.getFiles());
            //Since the request returns 'pages' of files, set the next page token
            request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
            request.setPageToken(null);
        }
    }
    while (request.getPageToken() != null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
    System.out.println(result.size());
    //Iterate through each folder retrieved
    for (int x = 0; x < result.size(); x++)
    {
        //List to store the folder's parents
        List<String> parents = new ArrayList<>();
        //If a root folder has been found
        boolean foundRoot = false;
        //Iterator to move up through the hierarchy of parent folders
        int parentIterator = -1;
        //While the root folder has not been found
        while (!foundRoot)
        {
            String parent = "";
            //If this is the first folder being iterated through
            if(parentIterator == -1)
            {
                //Retrieve the immediate parent of the folder, which is returned as a list of strings despite always being 1 entry
                //If there is no parent, null is returned
                List<String> tempParents = service.files().get(result.get(x).getId()).setFields("parents").execute().getParents();
                //If the file has a parent
                if(tempParents != null)
                {
                    //Save the parent to a variable
                    parent = tempParents.get(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Show the folder has no parent
                    parent = null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //This handles the parents of the first folder, iterating through them
                //Retrieve the immediate parent of the folder, which is returned as a list of strings despite always being 1 entry
                //If there is no parent, null is returned
                List<String> tempParents = service.files().get(parents.get(parentIterator)).setFields("parents").execute().getParents();
                //If the file has a parent
                if(tempParents != null)
                {
                    //Save the parent to a variable
                    parent = tempParents.get(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Show the folder has no parent
                    parent = null;
                }
            }
            //If there is a parent
            if (parent != null)
            {
                //Add the parent to the parents list
                parents.add(parent);
                parentIterator += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                //Otherwise the root has been found
                foundRoot = true;
            }
        }
        //Add the parents to the file
        result.get(x).setParents(parents);
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    //Sort the results based on the number of parents they have
    //NOT WORKING YET
    Collections.sort(result, new Comparator<File>()
    {

        public int compare(File o1, File o2)
        {
            return ((Integer)o1.getParents().size()).compareTo(o2.getParents().size());
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Thanks for any assistance you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Batching Requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/batch), wherein instead of sending each call separately, you can group them together into a single HTTP request.

And you may actually improve the performance of your API calls further, as given in [Working with partial resources](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/performance#partial):

> Another way to improve the performance of your API calls is by requesting only the portion of the data that you're interested in.

As also stated,

> By default, the server sends back the full representation of a resource after processing requests. For better performance, you can ask the server to send only the fields you really need and get a partial response instead.

You may find simple request for batching requests and partial reponses in the given documentations.